# Days since 1900

Tags: php, phpexcel, date-conversion

I'm using data from `Excel2007` as parsed by [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), and dates come out as days since 1900.

How can I convert to string of `YYYY-MM-DD` (or anything similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use

```
$phpDate = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getCalculatedValue());
```

to convert an Excel/PHPExcel date to a PHP date/timestamp, and then use standard PHP date() function for formatting

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, should do the trick:

```
PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($cell->getCalculatedValue(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 1):

purely php

```
 $datetime1 = new DateTime('1900-01-01');
 $datetime2 = new DateTime(); // today
 $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 $days=$interval->format('%a');
 $days+=2; // add boundary days
 echo $days;  // this is the number excel will use
```